# PHP & CSS: How to get hover effect for each row of a table?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table, hover

I am using this code to show events. Every event is clickable, but I really need a background-color hover-effect for this. Maybe it's also possible without JavaScript?

```
<table class="tableLine">
<tr>
<th>Wann?</th>
<th>Was?</th>
<th>Wer?</th>
<th>Wo?</th>
</tr>

<?php
$all_events = array();
$ten_events = array();

for($i = 0; $events = mysql_fetch_object($events_resource); $i++){

if($i < 9){

    $ten_events[] = $events;

}

$all_events[] = $events;

}  

$i = 0;

foreach($ten_events as $event){ 

$row = $i % 2;

echo "<tr onclick=\"window.location.href = '?page=single_event&amp;id=$event->id'\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">
        <td class='row_{$row}'>{$event->de_date}</td></a>
        <td class='row_{$row}'>{$event->category}</td>
        <td class='row_{$row}'>{$event->who}</td>
        <td class='row_{$row}'>{$event->location}</td>
      </tr>";

$i++;

} 
?>
```

**CSS**

Here is my CSS-code for the rows.

```
.tableLine {
font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 10px;
width: 614px;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
text-align: left;
}

.tableLine th {
background-color: #990000;
color: #f3f2ea;
font-weight: bold;
}

.row_0 {
background-color: #424140;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
color: #f3f2ea;
}

.row_1 {
background-color: #555352;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
color: #f3f2ea;
}

.tableLine tr:hover {
background: #990000;
}
```

Comment: Is `tr:hover` not working for you?

Comment: I think you mean `tr:hover`. He said each row, not each cell.

Comment: I updated both codes. I tried tr:hover for the tableline-class, but it did not work.

Comment: I added the tr:hover code, but it does not work.

Comment: Maybe it does not because of the _onclick_-stuff in the <tr>-echo?

Comment: No, it's because your `td` elements have `background-color` set. You need to set all the background colors to the `tr` elements or they will be overridden for the child `td`s.

Comment: Mike is right. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove the `class='row_{$row}'` from `td` and put it to `tr` tag
2. Then replace this part of your css:

/**/

```
.row_0 {
background-color: #424140;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
color: #f3f2ea;
}

.row_1 {
background-color: #555352;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
color: #f3f2ea;
}
```

with this:

```
.row_0 {
   background-color: #424140;
}

.row_1 {
   background-color: #555352;
}

.row_0:hover, .row_1:hover {
   background-color: #EEE; /* highlight row */
}

.tableLine tr td {
   padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
   color: #f3f2ea;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One little question: Is it possible to remove this _onclick_-JavaScript? That's a bad solution for me. If JavaScript is disabled no one can click on the links.

Comment: I know one way: put an `a` tag inside each `td`. Not the best solution but at least it will work w/o javascript. :P

Comment: I see, it's not perfect, beacause it's only clickable on the text, because the padding-area is not clickable, if JavaScript is disabled. But better than nothing. If anyone know a better solution: Feel free to post it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can add the padding to the `a` tag instead of setting the padding in `td`?

Comment: Yes, but the clickable area will only increase 5px to the left and the right. So, if there are 50 characters in a cell on line 1 and only 10 characters in line 2, the cell of line 1 has a width of 50 characters + padding. In line 2 the clickable area is only 10 characters + padding, and the space of about 40 characters is not clickable. Hope you understand.

Comment: Because anchor tags by default are inline elements. You need to set its `display` style to `block`.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I needed. Big thanks. Now the table looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS:

```
 tr:hover { background: #CCC; }
```

Comment: I tried:

`.tableLine tr:hover { background-color: #990000; }
`
This did not work for me.

Comment: Are you using an older version of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CSS`

```
table tr:hover{background:#eee;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to highlight each column as well you can give each column td a unique class and use something as below. (jQuery)

```
$("td").hover(
    // Mouse Over Function
    function () {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).each(function() {
            $(this).css("background","#FAFAFA");
        });
        $(this).parent().children("td").each(function() {$(this).css("background","#FAFAFA")});
        $(this).css("background","#FAEEFA");
    },
    // Mouse Out Function
    function () {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).each(function() {
            $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).css("background","#FFFFFF");
        });
        $(this).parent().children("td").each(function() {$(this).css("background","#FFFFFF")});
    });
```

Comment: I don't doubt that this would work, but Why would you use bloated jQuery to do a simple background change on hover?

Comment: @Mike I could not find a way to highlight the column using only html and css. If there is a way please let me know.

Comment: The OP said "row" not "column".

Comment: True but the answer was already given I though i would add some value. Notice i started with "If you also..." Just thought someone may find it helpful one day